# Remove divs around a div

Tags: jquery

**My HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="wrapper2">
     <div class="real_content"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Question**

Is there any way for me to remove the 2 divs around `<div class="real_content"></div>` so it won't appear on HTML and front end of my website? Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could try `.replaceWith()` ([docs](http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/)):

```
$('.wrapper').replaceWith( $('.real_content') );
```

There's also an `.unwrap()` function ([docs](http://api.jquery.com/unwrap/)), if you'd prefer a more relative way:

```
$('.real_content').unwrap().unwrap();
```

Comment: Thanks Matt. You just saved my time. :)

Answer (score 1):

The code will still appear in the HTML source if you replace it with jQuery, to hide it otherwise you would need to do it server side. To replace the DIVs with jQuery however, you can use [jQuery.replaceWith()](http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/) -

```
var content = $('.real_content');
$('.wrapper').replaceWith(content);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use `unwrap` in jQuery,

`$(".real_content").unwrap().unwrap();​`

http://api.jquery.com/unwrap/

Comment: Thanks but Matts answer worked.

Answer (score 1):

try `unwrap()`

```
$('.real_content').parent().unwrap();
```